# How to resample a dataframe an include start and end times?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

So I am working with tick data and I am attempting to resample the dataframe to minute bars, but when resample is called the time series begins and ends the first instance that a tick exists. How would I resample this data such that the first and last times can be specified to a certain start and end time?

Edit here is some sample data.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Code': pd.Series(['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], dtype='str'), 'Timestamp': pd.Series([1608627600073933, 1698929600124359, 1608627600073933, 1608929600124359], dtype='datetime64[ns]'),
'Val':[5, 6, 5, 6]})
df.set_index(['Timestamp'], inplace=True)
df.groupby('Code').resample('1T').agg('sum')
```

Which outputs

```
                     Val
Timestamp
1970-01-19 14:50:00    5
1970-01-19 14:51:00    0
1970-01-19 14:52:00    0
1970-01-19 14:53:00    0
1970-01-19 14:54:00    0
1970-01-19 14:55:00    6
```

But I would like an output dataframe that includes a timestamp for every minute of a specific hour for example.

Comment: Can you add some small sample data to question with your solution and also expected ouput from this sample?

Comment: Sure give me a sec.

Comment: Okay I have some code. Basically when I write resample, the time series goes from the first minute to the last minute the ticks are bucketed into. How do I specify that I want to return a time series that encompasses every minute of that day?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add start and end datetimes manually:

```
#removed minutes and seconds
df1 = df.rename(lambda x: x.floor('H'))
#removed duplicated DatetimeIndex - output empty df
df1 = df1.loc[~df1.index.duplicated(), []]
#join together
df1 = pd.concat([df, df1, df1.rename(lambda x: x + pd.Timedelta('00:59:00'))])
print (df1)
                              Code  Val
Timestamp                              
1970-01-19 14:50:27.600073933    A  5.0
1970-01-19 14:55:29.600124359    A  6.0
1970-01-19 14:00:00.000000000  NaN  NaN
1970-01-19 14:59:00.000000000  NaN  NaN

df2 = df1.resample('1T').agg('sum')
print (df2)
```

For add values per days:

```
df1 = df.rename(lambda x: x.floor('D'))
df1 = df1.loc[~df1.index.duplicated(), []]
df1 = pd.concat([df, df1, df1.rename(lambda x: x + pd.Timedelta('23:59:00'))])
print (df1)
                              Code  Val
Timestamp                              
1970-01-19 14:50:27.600073933    A  5.0
1970-01-19 14:55:29.600124359    A  6.0
1970-01-19 00:00:00.000000000  NaN  NaN
1970-01-19 23:59:00.000000000  NaN  NaN

df2 = df1.resample('1T').agg('sum')
print (df2)
```

Comment: This seems to work! Thank you so much!

Comment: Okay I understand your solution but this becomes wasteful when the tick data spans across several days since the first and last minutes are concatenated for each day, instead of the first possible time of the first day and the last possible time on the last day.

Comment: It is also causing me trouble when I have to check across tick data with differing time ranges for multiple codes.

Comment: @Anonymous - Can you create new question with this requirements? Because a bit busy.